# Storing the result of a foreach on a vector<string> in a container for serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, stl, c++17, file-handling

```
std::string reg = ("AA00 AAA");
// Open the file for reading
std::ifstream file_in("../data/history/"+reg+".his");

// populate vector with line string from file
std::vector<std::string> contents;
int i;
std::string line;
while(!file_in.eof( )) {
    std::getline(file_in, line);
    contents.emplace_back(line);
    i++;
}
// specify phrases for replacement 
std::string toReplace(" NA ");
std::string dateStamp = dateHelpers::getCurrentDate();

//initialize aux container 
std::vector<std::string> newLineVec;

//perform replacment
std::for_each(contents.begin(), contents.end(),[dateStamp](auto line){  // << was capturing newLineVec Here.
    int index;
    std::cout << "Initial String :" << line << std::endl;
    while((index = line.find("NA")) != std::string::npos) {    //for each location where phrase is present
        line.replace(index, dateStamp.length(), dateStamp);      //remove & replace at that position
        std::cout << "Final String :" << line << std::endl;
        // newLineVec.emplace_back(line);                             // store results ???
         }
     }
);
```

My goal is to search & replace instances of word in a text file. I can not seem to use the result of the for each to populate a container to then stream back to the input file.
Is my approach here sensible or am I way off track?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried to make the snippet minimally reproducible so any input on how I could improve my question asking would also go a long way.

Edit* output example ..

```
Initial String :james smith 88 broad lane 07474493221 2021/05/12 NA
Final String :james smith 88 broad lane 07474493221 2021/05/12 2022/12/14
Initial String :adam brown  42 church street 07392834769 2022/03/03 NA
Final String :adam brown  42 church street 07392834769 2022/03/03 2022/12/14
Initial String :James smith 88 broad lane 07474493221 2022/09/12 NA
Final String :James smith 88 broad lane 07474493221 2022/09/12 2022/12/14
```

**edit2 -> I apologise as I must have been tired last night as all is well this morning. The long day must have got the better of me. Here's it cleaned up a little. Now to work on guarding to avoid potential seg faults..

```
void storeLineFiles(std::vector<std::string> &linesVec, const std::string path){
    // Open the file for reading
    std::ifstream file_in(path);

    // populate container with lines from file (strings)
    int i;
    std::string line;
    while(!file_in.eof( )) {
        std::getline(file_in, line);
        linesVec.emplace_back(line);
        i++;
    }
}
void replaceStrContainerWords(std::vector<std::string> &input, const std::string toReplace, const std::string &replacement){
    //initialize aux container
    std::vector<std::string> newLineVec;

    //for each line in input vec + capture env vars
    std::for_each(input.begin(), input.end(),[ &toReplace, &replacement, &newLineVec](auto line){
                      int index;
    //replace all instances of toReplace with replacement
                      while((index = line.find(toReplace)) != std::string::npos) {    //for each location where phrase is present
                          line.replace(index, replacement.length(), replacement);   //remove & replace at that position
                          newLineVec.emplace_back(line);                            // store result temporarily in aux container
                      }
                  }
    );
    input = newLineVec; // copy result to input container for ergonomics.
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::string reg = ("AA00 AAA");
    std::string path = ("../data/history/" + reg + ".his");
    std::vector<std::string> toChange;
    storeLineFiles(toChange, path);
    for (auto each : toChange) { std::cout << each << "\n"; }

    std::string toReplace("NA");
    std::string dateStamp = dateHelpers::getCurrentDate();
    replaceStrContainerWords(toChange, toReplace, dateStamp);
    for (auto each : toChange) { std::cout << each << "\n"; }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output as well? What happens when you currently try to run the program?

Comment: What does "I can not seem to use the result of the for each to populate a container to then stream back to the input file" mean? This is like describing a problem with your car as "I cannot seem to make it go forward and make 'Vroom!' noises". There seems to be multiple bugs in the shown code, and it's not clear which specific bug you're asking about.

Comment: Output added. I wanted to focus on achieving the result before error guarding.

Comment: If the result is not what you expect, the next step is debugging to find out why, and one way of doing that is checking for failures, that is error guarding.  Other things to do are single-stepping through code in a debugger after setting breakpoints, or adding logging.  Learning to debug is a key skill for a developer.

Comment: The result of the for each is as I'd hoped, though I'm unsure of how I can store the result rather than printing. streaming to an ofstream does not seem to work & I'm unsure how to manipulate the return type to store in a vector<string>

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, but code like `while(!file_in.eof( ))` is almost always broken (including this case). A loop like `while (std::getline(file_in, line)) contents.emplace_back(line);` will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to store the data in a container, you can read each line, replace your pattern-string with your replacement-string and output it in a single loop.

here is pseudo-code

```
open input file
while (not end of file)
{
    read 1 line
    if pattern in line, then replace it
    print output
}
```

Comment: `while (not end of file)` is almost always broken. What you really want it `while (read from file succeeded) ...`

Comment: I was hoping this would be possible but I assumed that in the same way I'm cout'ing the result, I would be able to stream to an ofstream object in the same way, ie, out_file << line. But I am not able to.

Answer (score 0):

I created a minimum reproducable example.

I corrected the problem that you forgot to pass the parameter "line" to the lambda as reference. So, in your above example:

```
std::for_each(input.begin(), input.end(),[ &toReplace, &replacement, &newLineVec](auto line){
```

So, the `&` before the word "line"

The corrected MRE looks like the below and works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void replaceStrContainerWords(std::vector<std::string> &input, const std::string &toReplace, const std::string &replacement){

    //for each line in input vec + capture env vars
    std::for_each(input.begin(), input.end(),[ &toReplace, &replacement](auto &line){
        int index;
        //replace all instances of toReplace with replacement
            while((index = line.find(toReplace)) != std::string::npos) {    //for each location where phrase is present
                line.replace(index, replacement.length(), replacement);   //remove & replace at that position
           }
       }
    );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::vector<std::string> toChange{
        {"james smith 88 broad lane 07474493221 2021/05/12 NA"},
        {"adam brown  42 church street 07392834769 2022/03/03 NA"}};
        
    std::string toReplace("NA");
    std::string dateStamp{"9988776655"};
    
    replaceStrContainerWords(toChange, toReplace, dateStamp);
    
    for (auto each : toChange) { std::cout << each << "\n"; }
}
```